Why does roxygen2 declare my function as S3method in NAMESPACE?
This is my function:
#' @title core text wrapping function
#' @param x the text input
#' @param len the maximum length for each of line
#' @return the wrapped text
#' @examples wrap.it("a long string bla bla bla", 10)
#' @export
wrap.it <- function(x, len)
{
    sapply(x, function(y) paste(strwrap(y, len),
                                collapse = "\n"),
           USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}

and when i use devtools::document("./XX") to producing NAMESPACE files, it will be:
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method(wrap,it)

what can i do

Possibly because it includes a dot . in its name.  Do you have the same problem if you rename it to wrap_it?  (Which I believe is current best practice but I don't have a reference to hand to back that up.)  Here's a reference.

@Limey thank you, according to your suggestion, both approaches work.
